# Wordpress REST API : How to Create post and attach Featured Image to post after creation?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using a form that has a image upload/input field, which allows authenticated users to create and publish a post via WP API. I got the post creation function working, however I'm stuck on the adding featured image part.

I am aware that in order to upload a featured image and assign it to the post, the post must be created first.

Here's the code that I'm thinking will work but not sure what methods are best to program for success and the desired outcome. Any help is much appreciated :

**Desired Outcome**

- Create Post From Submitted Form with img File
- Variable Newly Created Post Id
- Variable img file
- Create new media post that is attached to post id just created (to set as featured image)
- Display success alert

**My Code so far Trigger When From Is Submitted**

```
           // trigger when post form is submitted
$(document).on('submit', '#post_form', function(){
  var jwt = getCookie('jwt');
    // get form data
    var post_form=$(this);
    var form_data=JSON.stringify(post_form.serializeObject());


   // submit form data to api to create post
$.ajaxSetup({

    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : form_data,
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"Bearer"+ jwt);
};
    $.post("https://my-domain.here/wp-json/wp/v2/customendpoint").then(function(result) {
    $(data).each(function(index, value) {
      var postid = value.id;
     }

    // What goes here to grab postid?
   // How do I assign variable to the file from the submitted form ??
   // And can/how should I perform another POST to media endpoint with posid to assign feature image after post creation is complete? 


            $.ajaxSetup({

        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : form_data,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"Bearer"+ jwt);
};
    $.post("http://my-domain.here/wp-json/wp/v2/media").done(function(result) {

//something here to show success

});
});

    return false;
});
```